# How should I configure Swagger on a separate domain for Azure Mobile (to resolve security issue)

Tags: security, azure, xss, swagger, azure-mobile-services

This [wiki link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Adding-Swagger-Metadata-and-Help-UI-to-a-Mobile-App) has the following advisory about Swagger

> NOTE: The 0.3.157.1 version of Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Swagger depends on a version the swagger-ui JavaScript library that has a security vulnerability. See https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/126.

The advice from [NodeSecurity](https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/126) is

> Our primary recommendation is to host swagger documentation on a separate domain distinct from the application domain. Also, we recommend implementing a content security policy (CSP) that restricts the domains from which JSON files can be requested in order to avoid loading malicious JSON docs via the URL query string parameter.

What is the most straightforward way to accommodate this advice?

Should I use a separate TLD, or is a subdomain acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

For quick test, I leverage http://petstore.swagger.io/ for simulating this scenario. If I have any misunderstanding about your scenario, please let me know.

Add the swagger-ui endpoint into the `CORS` settings in the portal:
[image]

Use the public swagger endpoiont in the separate swagger-ui client:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Should I use `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Swagger` to create the client facing Swashbuckle? If so, how do I edit `config. EnableSwagger()` to expose  this GUI on a separate DNS domain endpoint? (assume I already added the CORS support as you describe)

Comment: It seems that you are using mobile app in C#, sorry I know little about C#, but in my test, the endpoint `<mobile_app_endpoint>/swagger` response the entire swagger config content in json, which can be used directly in swagger-ui. https://garytestmb.azurewebsites.net/swagger, FYI